# CoroutineContext best practices in a Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to understand what are the best practices on how to use kotlin coroutines in a Spring server application, specifically about the `CoroutineContext`.
Let's say I have a `Controller` like this:

```
@Controller
class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var productRepository: ProductRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mapper: ProductDtoMapper
   
    @GetMapping("/")
    suspend fun getProduct(): ProductDTO {
        val product = productRepository.getFirst()
        val productDTO = mapper.mapToDto(product)
        return productDto
    }
}
```

Then my `Repository` is like:

```
@Repository
class ProductRepository(private val productService: ProductService) {

    suspend fun getFirst(): Product = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return productService.get()
    }
}
```

I noticed that the code inside the `getProduct` function is executed in a `CoroutineContext` that is `Unconfined`, which means that in the example above, after `productRepository.getFirst()` returns, the execution resumes in the same thread defined in the `ProductRepository.getFirst` method.

Now, in this specific example probably this doesn't matter but I was thinking that with the application growing, this might cause some problems.
For example, let's say that the `ProductService` is doing some operations that is blocking the thread: in this case I could decide to create a fixed number of threads to limit the amount of threads to handle this kind of operation. The code might look to something like this:

```
@Repository
class ProductRepository(private val productService: ProductService) {
   
    private val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).asCoroutineDispatcher()

    suspend fun getFirst(): Product = withContext(dispatcher) {
        return productService.get()
    }
}
```

So, as stated above, after `productRepository.getFirst()` returns, the execution resumes in the same thread defined in the `ProductRepository.getFirst` method.
That means that also the mapping in `ProductController` will be executed in the same thread, and if this is also a blocking operation the thread will continue to execute operations that was not suppose to execute.

I come from Android and this kind of behavior is not recommended, since it might end up executing code that is doing cpu intensive operations in the main thread and this will be blocking the ui.

So, back to the server application, I would define the `CoroutineContext` that I want to use in the `ProductController` so I will be sure that the code after `productRepository.getFirst()` will be executed in the same context that I decided to be. It would look to something like this:

```
@Controller
class ProductController {

   // other code
   
    @GetMapping("/")
    suspend fun getProduct(): ProductDTO = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val product = productRepository.getFirst()
        val productDTO = mapper.mapToDto(product)
        return productDto
    }
}
```

In this way I found way more easier mentally track the context in which the code is executed.

So my questions are:

- Is it fine to use this `Unconfined` context?
- Might this behavior be a problem when need to scale the application?
- What is a good practice for this case?

If I wrote something wrong or my question is not clear let me know.